# Django server not opening with 0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: django, nginx

I have a AWS server runs on Nginx and which hosts a React application working fine on server.
Now I want a Django app for restframework to be available on the same server.

Iam following the [Document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) and uploaded the Django app on the server and try to run the app by trying `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. There is no error but I cannot access my ip with `http://server_domain_or_IP:8000`.

Nginx config at /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.org.conf

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name example.org;
        return 301 https://example.org;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.org;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

        location / {
                root /home/ubuntu/example/build;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }
}
```

Please help where am I going wrong?

Comment: show your nginx setup.

Comment: Hi @RanuVijay, Added Nginx config

Comment: Hope example.org is a placeholder and not the actual domain name, otherwise, it is clearly the problem that it does not point to your registered domain. Also firewalls, closed ports, DNS settings, etc etc etc...

Comment: Yes example.org is just for demo purpose. I made the configs regarding my live domain

Answer (score 0):

So your Django is running on localhost:8000 and in your Nginx setup, you are not forwarding your request to that address. You have to match the domain request with your Django running server, In production, you should have something like **Gunicorn**

Try with -

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:8000;
}
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
     }
```

this would work for non-https. You can add **listen 443 ssl**, and SSL certificates to make your server block listen only to HTTPS.